# com.docker.docker repository doesn't display it's real name

Tags: filesystem, docker

I have Docker on my Mac and just for curiosity's sake, I went to the `Docker` repository to see a bit how it is : `~/Library/Containers/Docker`

But this repository is kind of strange. When I display its info, it is written that its real name is `com.docker.docker` while it displays `Docker`.

Anyone knows how it is possible ?